# why pyarrow not detect invalid_row_handler when parsing param as open_csv(**args)

Tags: python, pyarrow, ray

I'm trying add `invalid_row_handler` to pyarrow ParseOptions when working with rllib but it just ignore it and throw invalid row error.

Test code:

```
invalid_content = '''src_ip,dst_ip,src_port,dst_port,src_mac,dst_mac,protocol,timestamp,flow_duration,flow_byts_s,flow_pkts_s,fwd_pkts_s,bwd_pkts_s,tot_fwd_pkts,tot_bwd_pkts,totlen_fwd_pkts,totlen_bwd_pkts,fwd_pkt_len_max,fwd_pkt_len_min,fwd_pkt_len_mean,fwd_pkt_len_std,bwd_pkt_len_max,bwd_pkt_len_min,bwd_pkt_len_mean,bwd_pkt_len_std,pkt_len_max,pkt_len_min,pkt_len_mean,pkt_len_std,pkt_len_var,fwd_header_len,bwd_header_len,fwd_seg_size_min,fwd_act_data_pkts,flow_iat_mean,flow_iat_max,flow_iat_min,flow_iat_std,fwd_iat_tot,fwd_iat_max,fwd_iat_min,fwd_iat_mean,fwd_iat_std,bwd_iat_tot,bwd_iat_max,bwd_iat_min,bwd_iat_mean,bwd_iat_std,fwd_psh_flags,bwd_psh_flags,fwd_urg_flags,bwd_urg_flags,fin_flag_cnt,syn_flag_cnt,rst_flag_cnt,psh_flag_cnt,ack_flag_cnt,urg_flag_cnt,ece_flag_cnt,down_up_ratio,pkt_size_avg,init_fwd_win_byts,init_bwd_win_byts,active_max,active_min,active_mean,active_std,idle_max,idle_min,idle_mean,idle_std,fwd_byts_b_avg,fwd_pkts_b_avg,bwd_byts_b_avg,bwd_pkts_b_avg,fwd_blk_rate_avg,bwd_blk_rate_avg,fwd_seg_size_avg,bwd_seg_size_avg,cwe_flag_count,subflow_fwd_pkts,subflow_bwd_pkts,subflow_fwd_byts,subflow_bwd_byts
16.12.5.10,192.168.66.180,443,58842,,,6,2022-08-21 13:13:16,121.0,24330578.512396693,16528.92561983471,16528.92561983471,0.0,2,0,2944,0,1472.0,1472.0,1472.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1472,1472,1472.0,0.0,0.0,40,0,20,2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,1472.0,251,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1472.0,0.0,0,2,0,2944,0
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'''

source = 'test.csv'
with open(source, 'w') as f:
    f.write(invalid_content)

import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow import csv, fs
parse_options = csv.ParseOptions(delimiter=",", invalid_row_handler=lambda i: 'skip')
fields = 'src_ip,dst_ip,src_port,dst_port,src_mac,dst_mac,' \
'protocol,timestamp,flow_duration,flow_byts_s,flow_pkts_s,' \
'fwd_pkts_s,bwd_pkts_s,tot_fwd_pkts,tot_bwd_pkts,totlen_fwd_pkts,' \
'totlen_bwd_pkts,fwd_pkt_len_max,fwd_pkt_len_min,fwd_pkt_len_mean,' \
'fwd_pkt_len_std,bwd_pkt_len_max,bwd_pkt_len_min,bwd_pkt_len_mean,' \
'bwd_pkt_len_std,pkt_len_max,pkt_len_min,pkt_len_mean,pkt_len_std,' \
'pkt_len_var,fwd_header_len,bwd_header_len,fwd_seg_size_min,' \
'fwd_act_data_pkts,flow_iat_mean,flow_iat_max,flow_iat_min,flow_iat_std,' \
'fwd_iat_tot,fwd_iat_max,fwd_iat_min,fwd_iat_mean,fwd_iat_std,bwd_iat_tot,' \
'bwd_iat_max,bwd_iat_min,bwd_iat_mean,bwd_iat_std,fwd_psh_flags,bwd_psh_flags,' \
'fwd_urg_flags,bwd_urg_flags,fin_flag_cnt,syn_flag_cnt,rst_flag_cnt,psh_flag_cnt,' \
'ack_flag_cnt,urg_flag_cnt,ece_flag_cnt,down_up_ratio,pkt_size_avg,' \
'init_fwd_win_byts,init_bwd_win_byts,active_max,active_min,active_mean,active_std,' \
'idle_max,idle_min,idle_mean,idle_std,fwd_byts_b_avg,fwd_pkts_b_avg,bwd_byts_b_avg,' \
'bwd_pkts_b_avg,fwd_blk_rate_avg,bwd_blk_rate_avg,fwd_seg_size_avg,bwd_seg_size_avg,' \
'cwe_flag_count,subflow_fwd_pkts,subflow_bwd_pkts,subflow_fwd_byts,subflow_bwd_byts'\
    .split(',')

# working well
f = fs.LocalFileSystem().open_input_stream(source)
schema = {i: pa.string() for i in fields}
convert_options = csv.ConvertOptions(column_types=schema)
read_options = csv.ReadOptions(use_threads=False)
reader = csv.open_csv(f, read_options=read_options, **{'parse_options': parse_options, 'convert_options': convert_options})
batch = reader.read_next_batch()
table = pa.Table.from_batches([batch], schema=None)
print(batch)
# end working well

# working fail with invalid row error
import ray
from ray.data.dataset_pipeline import DatasetPipeline
from ray.data.datasource import FastFileMetadataProvider
from ray.runtime_env import RuntimeEnv

import os
os.environ["RAY_DATASET_FORCE_LOCAL_METADATA"] = "1"
runtime_env = RuntimeEnv(pip={
            "packages": ["tensorflow==2.7.0", "numpy==1.21.4", "six==1.16.0", "numba==0.56.0", "pyarrow==9.0.0"],
            "pip_check": False,
            "pip_version": "==22.2.2;python_version=='3.7.3'"})
ray.init(runtime_env=runtime_env)

data_files = [source]
pipe: DatasetPipeline = ray.data.read_csv(
    data_files,
    meta_provider=FastFileMetadataProvider(),
    parse_options=parse_options,
    convert_options=convert_options,
).window(blocks_per_window=500)

print(pipe.count())
# end working fail with invalid row error
```

After re-init ParseOptions by edit code of rllib at https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/e4ce38d001dbbe09cd21c497fedd03d692b2be3e/python/ray/data/datasource/csv_datasource.py#L34
From

```
reader = csv.open_csv(f, read_options=read_options, **reader_args)
```

To

```
parse_options = reader_args["parse_options"]
reader_args["parse_options"]=csv.ParseOptions(delimiter=parse_options.delimiter, invalid_row_handler=parse_options.invalid_row_handler)
reader = csv.open_csv(f, read_options=read_options, **reader_args)
```

Then it works fine.
Could any help me explain why csv.open_csv(..., **reader_args) in ray doesn't work when parse_options is not re-initialize? and is there any way to bypass this without edit ray code?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with pyarrow serialization/deserialization. I've posted it here: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/28326 and we will track progress there. Note that it's likely that the bug is actually within pyarrow. We will still try to provide a workaround in Ray soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As tracked in https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/28326, this is an issue on the pyarrow side with deserializing ParseOptions objects. We've filed a fix for Ray in https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/28327 which will be included in the 2.1 release. Once the fix is merged you can use the latest master wheels (the "nightly wheels") to run your job without issues.
We've also filed a fix on the pyarrow side in https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/14061 and it's likely to be included in one of the next releases.

In the meantime, to use your current Ray version without any changes, you can create your own custom CSV datasource to work around the problem:

```
class CustomCSVDatasource(ray.data.datasource.CSVDatasource):
    def _read_stream(
        self, f: "pyarrow.NativeFile", path: str, **reader_args
    ):
        import pyarrow
        from pyarrow import csv

        read_options = reader_args.pop(
            "read_options", csv.ReadOptions(use_threads=False)
        )
        parse_options = reader_args.pop("parse_options", csv.ParseOptions())
        # Re-init invalid row handler: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-17641
        if hasattr(parse_options, "invalid_row_handler"):
            parse_options.invalid_row_handler = parse_options.invalid_row_handler

        reader = csv.open_csv(
            f, read_options=read_options, parse_options=parse_options, **reader_args
        )
        schema = None
        while True:
            try:
                batch = reader.read_next_batch()
                table = pyarrow.Table.from_batches([batch], schema=schema)
                if schema is None:
                    schema = table.schema
                yield table
            except StopIteration:
                return


data_files = [source]
pipe: DatasetPipeline = ray.data.read_datasource(
    CustomCSVDatasource(),
    paths=data_files,
    meta_provider=FastFileMetadataProvider(),
    parse_options=parse_options,
    convert_options=convert_options,
).window(blocks_per_window=500)
```

Comment: Could you provide any way to by pass this on ray==1.13.0? upgrading ray might make me rather heavy on upgrading related other libs.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my original answer. Please let me know if this solves your problem